# obtener valor de select html en vb.net

Tags: javascript, html5, vb.net

Tengo problemas para recuperar un valor seleccionado de un `<select>` o combo de html desde VB.NET, tengo 3 `<div>` cada uno con cierta función y para que aparezca solo el `<div>` que seleccione el usuario oculto los otros dos.

El problema es que no puedo obtener el valor que se ha seleccionado. Cuando intento recuperar la variable de servidor "cd", obtengo el ultimo valor del switch de la función JavaScript, es decir `cd="ciudad3"` y no el que seleccione.

```js
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    @code dim var cd As String end code
        var x = document.getElementById("sucursal").value;

        switch (x) {
            case "":
                alert("seleccion incorrecta")
                break;
            case "ciudad1":
                document.getElementById("ciudad2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("ciudad3").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("ciudad1").style.display = "block";
                @code cd="ciudad1" end code
                break;
            case "ciudad2":
                document.getElementById("ciudad1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("ciudad3").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("ciudad2").style.display = "block";
                @code cd="ciudad1" end code
                break;
            case "ciudad3":
                document.getElementById("ciudad2").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("ciudad1").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("ciudad3").style.display = "block";
                @code cd="ciudad1" end code
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
            Directorio
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Sucursal</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sucursal" name="sucursal" onchange="myFunction()">
                    <option value="">-- Seleccione una opción --</option>
                    <option value="ciudad1">Ciudad uno</option>
                    <option value="ciudad2">Ciudad dos</option>
                    <option value="ciudad3">Ciudad tres</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
   </div
</div>
```

```html
@code
      'Dim x As String = Request.Form("sucursal")

    Try

        Dim cn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("directorio").ConnectionString

        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conexion
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM directorio WHERE idcIUDAD = '"& cd &"' ORDER BY puesto DESC"
        conexion.Open()

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
          dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
          If dr.Read() Then End code
              <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" >@dr.Item("Puesto")</div>
               <strong>Nombre.:</strong><div>@dr.Item("nombre")</div>
                <strong>Telefono.:</strong><div>@dr.Item("telefono")</div>
                <strong>Extensión.:</strong><div>@dr.Item("ext")</div> 
                <strong>E-mail.:</strong><div>@dr.Item("correo_electronico")</div>                                  
          @code    
                  End If
          end code


        @Code Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Error" + ex.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Fónix")
    End Try
End Code
```

Lo he intentado con `request.Form("sucursal")`, pero no me obtiene nada.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que trabajes desde javascript no podrias obtenerlos en codigo .net salvo que lo envies en un post. 
Una forma simple es asignar el valor a un hidden en asp.net, o se si en la pagina defines

```
<asp:Hidden id="sucursal" runat="server" />
```

podrias desde javascript asignar el valor usando

```
document.getElementById("<%=sucursal.ClientID%>").value = valor;
```

de esta forma al darse el evento al servidor podrias tomar el valor directo desde el hidden, ya que interviene en el post al ser un control de asp.net

---

Otra forma podrias ser usan ajax, para esto deberias evaluar usar jquery, por medio de $.ajax, podrias invocar WebMethod en la pagina aspx, en este caso los datos los tomarias con codigo cliente y los envias al servidor, no hay postback ni eventos.

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

El unico tema aqui es que necesitas que la pagina tenga `codebehind` o sea que existe un `aspx.vb` asociado al `aspx` ya que es alli donde defines el `[WebMethod]` que invocaras con ajax